# Why won't my USB headset show up in `lsusb` or `dmesg`?

Tags: usb, headset

I was given a [Turtle Beach XL1](http://www.turtlebeach.com/product-detail/ps4-headsets/ear-force-xl1/54) headset for Christmas.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to get it to work.

On the Windows machine I tried it on, you plug in the USB cable and it works.  Not much setup required.

On my Ubuntu machine, not so lucky.  Nothing happens.  The LED on the headset turns on, so I know it's getting power at least, but `lsusb` doesn't show it:

```
john@john:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c03d Logitech, Inc. M-BT96a Pilot Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:0730 Microsoft Corp. Digital Media Keyboard 3000
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and `dmesg` doesn't mention it either:

```
john@john:~$ dmesg | grep usb
[    0.177664] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.177669] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.177684] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.917391] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.917392] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.917393] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.917395] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.917396] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    0.933383] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.933385] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.933386] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.933387] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-43-generic ehci_hcd
[    0.933388] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.229472] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.361724] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.361726] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.473458] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.605716] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    1.605721] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.677457] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    1.792231] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0730
[    1.792236] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.792239] usb 1-1.3: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000
[    1.792241] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[    1.861619] usb 1-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    1.959226] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c03d
[    1.959231] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.959234] usb 1-1.4: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[    1.959236] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    2.375748] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.375750] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.378882] input: Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input5
[    2.378959] microsoft 0003:045E:0730.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
[    2.380363] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/input/input6
[    2.380480] hid-generic 0003:046D:C03D.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.4/input0
[    2.381368] input: Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/input/input7
[    2.381435] microsoft 0003:045E:0730.0002: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input1
[ 7636.371416] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 7636.828529] usb 1-1.3: new low-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 7636.943278] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0730
[ 7636.943284] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 7636.943287] usb 1-1.3: Product: Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000
[ 7636.943290] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Microsoft
[ 7636.952307] input: Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input15
[ 7636.952604] microsoft 0003:045E:0730.0004: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input0
[ 7636.968068] input: Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/input/input16
[ 7636.968242] microsoft 0003:045E:0730.0005: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Microsoft Microsoft\xffffffc2\xffffffae\xffffffae Digital Media Keyboard 3000] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3/input1
[ 7637.160501] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 7637.254736] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, idProduct=4366
[ 7637.254741] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 7637.254745] usb 2-1.2: Product: XT912
[ 7637.254747] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Motorola
[ 7637.254750] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 014F8B8213016004
[ 7637.284064] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 7637.284113] scsi4 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[ 7637.284172] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[ 7640.473488] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[ 7640.672357] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 7640.765649] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, idProduct=431d
[ 7640.765654] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 7640.765657] usb 2-1.2: Product: XT912
[ 7640.765660] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Motorola
[ 7640.765662] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 014F8B8213016004
[ 7640.808313] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
[ 7640.812879] rndis_host 2-1.2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, RNDIS device, a6:06:37:ce:b4:d4
[ 7640.812902] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[15709.587248] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[15709.589094] rndis_host 2-1.2:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2, RNDIS device
[15709.809300] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[15709.903294] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, idProduct=4366
[15709.903299] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[15709.903302] usb 2-1.2: Product: XT912
[15709.903305] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Motorola
[15709.903308] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 014F8B8213016004
[15709.904931] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[15709.905161] scsi5 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[15760.688462] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 5
```

What should I do?

Comment: Unplug the USB headset and run this command `watch -n1 "dmesg | tail -n 30"` . Keep the terminal open and plug the headset. Then copy-paste here the any messages.

Comment: Are you sure thus is **not** a *USB powered* amplifier, that connects using *standard* audio connectors?

Comment: @david6 I am sure.  There aren't any connections for standard audio connectors on the headset.

Comment: @NikTh There is no change in the output when I plug in the headset.

Comment: david6 is right, the audio input is to the amp, not the headset, so the usb is power only I guess.

Comment: Yes, but power only for what ? If that's the case, then look at sound settings and see if any "headphones" device is listed there.

Comment: @NikTh I see no entry for any "headphones" device.  I have found nothing whatsoever on the computer that acknowledges the existence of the headset.